# jQuery position DIV fixed at top on scroll except homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prestashop

I'm using this js & css to fixed jQuery position DIV at top on scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 135) {
        $('#task_flyout').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#task_flyout').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

```js
.fixed {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

and its working fine for me, but now I want to use this fixed menu on all pages except the homepage, I mean my menu will be fixed on scroll at all pages without the homepage. (again i don't want to fixed my homepage menu but need to fixed on all other pages)

Can somebody help me please?...

Comment: Hey, please, if you consider, mark my answer by clicking the `✔` button (left side of the answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check if you're on the homepage:

```
if (location.pathname === "/") {
    $('#task_flyout').removeClass('fixed');
} else {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 135) {
            $('#task_flyout').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('#task_flyout').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Daer Honorable,
THank u very much for kind response, I'm using prestashop, is it work with prestashop?

Comment: Yeah, it should work. Don't forget to mark the answer by clicking the `✔` button (left side of the answer).